# Difficulty Creating Pthreads (Error 22)

Tags: c, pthreads

Learning about pthreads, but I'm having trouble getting them created. Here is my output and the gdb information:

```
In main(), creating thread 1 
ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is 22 for thread 1
In main(), creating thread 2
ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is 22 for thread 2
In main(), creating thread 3
ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is 22 for thread 3
In main(), creating thread 4
ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is 22 for thread 4
In main(), creating thread 5
ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is 22 for thread 5

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7fb4d8a in
pthread_join (threadid=76038327, thread_return=0x0)
    at pthread_join.c:46 46 pthread_join.c: No such file or directory.
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SBUFSIZE 1025

char errorstr[SBUFSIZE];
FILE* inputfp[5];

void* f(void* inpFile) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", (char*)inpFile);
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int i;

    /* Thread Variables */
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t *th[argc-2]; //one thread for each input file

    /* allocate memory for the threads */
    for (i = 0; i < (argc-2); i++) {
        th[i] = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)); 
        inputfp[i] = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (!inputfp[i]) {
            sprintf(errorstr, "Error Opening Input File: %s", argv[i]);
            perror(errorstr);
        }
    }

    /* Create one thread for each input file */
    for (i = 1; i < (argc - 1); i++) {
        fprintf (stderr, "In main(), creating thread %1d\n", i);
        int rc = pthread_create (th[i], &attr, f, inputfp[i-1]);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d for thread %d\n",
                rc, i);
        }
    }

    /* wait for the threads to finish */
    for (i = 1; i < (argc - 1); i++) {
        pthread_join(*th[i], 0);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm missing something, but I don't know what. Can anyone help? Thank you!

EDIT: Here is how I changed the code per the suggestion from Joachim Pileborg. I'm still getting error 22 returning from pthread_create(), but the SIGSEGV error on pthread_join is no longer occurring.

Anyone have any suggestions about how I can get the pthread_create() to return 0 (indicating a successful thread creation)? Thanks again!

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int i;

    /* Thread Variables */
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t *th[argc-2]; //one thread for each input file

    /* allocate memory for the threads */
    for (i = 0; i < (argc-2); i++) {
        th[i] = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)); 
        printf("%s\n", argv[i+1]);
        inputfp[i] = fopen(argv[i+1], "r");
        if (!inputfp[i]) {
            sprintf(errorstr, "Error Opening Input File: %s", argv[i]);
            perror(errorstr);
        }
    }

    /* Create one thread for each input file */
    for (i = 0; i < (argc - 2); i++) {
        fprintf (stderr, "In main(), creating thread %1d\n", i);
        int rc = pthread_create (th[i], &attr, f, inputfp[i]);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d for thread %d\n",
                rc, i);
        }
    }

    /* wait for the threads to finish */
    for (i = 0; i < (argc - 2); i++) {
        pthread_join(*th[i], 0);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It's good that you use GDB to help you debug, but when you get the segmenation fault you can use the `bt` command to show the function call stack, and use `up` to go up the call stack. After using `up` to reach your code, you can `print` variables to see if they look okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one loop where you loop from zero to `argc - 3`, and uses the correct indexes (zero to "size of array minus one".

Then you have two loops where you loop from one to `argc - 2`, and use indexes from one to "size of array".

You should use the same loop as the first one in all three places.

Comment: Thank you. I added my updated code above. This cleared the SIGSEGV error, but I'm still not getting the correct return value from pthread_create(). Can you see why?

Comment: @usr55410 The value returned by `pthread_create` is the actual error number, so you can use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to print it out. I'm guessing it's going to be the error `EINVAL`, as the `attr` structure has not ben initialized. If you don't need to set any attribute then you can pass a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Looks like that was it. I changed &attr to NULL and now things seem to run just fine. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help!